# File upload returns empty result

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am new to laravel 5 and php so i cant understand why I get this problem.

I am trying to upload a file(video or image) using ajax but the server return an empty result. Even when I console the FormData the form seems empty.

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-file" role="form" method="POST" action="" >
     <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()}}">
     <input type="file" class="form-control" id="catagry-logo" name="videologo">
</form>
<div id="video-submit">Submit</div>
```

Javascript

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     headers: {
          'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')
     }
});

$('#video-submit').on('click', function() {
     console.log(new FormData($("#upload-file")[0]));
     $.ajax({
          type:'post',
          url:'uploadvideo',
          data: new FormData($("#upload_form")[0]),
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          success:function(response){
               console.log(response);
          }
     });
});
```

Route

```
Route::post('/uploadvideo', 'UploadController@videoUpload');
```

Controller

```
public function videoUpload() {
    return response()->json(json_encode(Input::all()));
}
```

Response

```
FormData {}
[]
```

Comment: Use the Request Class `public function videoUpload( Request $request )` then use `dd( $request->input( 'videologo' ) )`

Comment: Why is your action="" empty?

Comment: It means POST to self

Comment: He using ajax to post image. No need to add action on form

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the `Input` Facade

Try familiarizing yourself with the `Request` Class

And, the way you are returning your JSON response seems wrong, so try this.

> **NOTE**
>
> Make sure that the PHP Post Upload size in your INI file can handle the file size of your uploads or you will end up with blank POST requests
>
> On your `php.ini` file set the following directives to accomodate your uploads
>
> - `post_max_size` = (size in mb, the total size of the POST request)
> - `upload_max_filesize` = (size in mb, size of a single file in a POST request)

Controller

```
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;

public function videoUpload( Request $request ) {
    return response()->json( ['video' => $request->input( 'videologo' )] );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now i'am getting a null data, my test file size is only 35KB and still cant return a proper data

Comment: you should really try posting a string and see if it returns the exact string you posted.

Comment: I have already passed the data to the controller like string and int.